# Testcontainers parallel tests

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have a multi module Gradle project where I use testcontainers for the integration tests.

My initial idea was to share a container for all tests to run against the issue is that each test suite starts it´s own container.

I used the Singleton approach described here: https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/

I marked as well the container as reusable but I get the same behaviour. One container per test suite.

How can I make only start one container and that all tests suites share that one?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe share your codes help people spot your issue?

Comment: You can use the code provided in the link. It was the same issue